# Can one changing value by pointer from the parent process?

Tags: c, multiprocessing

I try to change a `_Bool` flag used as `while` loop parameter inside of a child process. The child needs to exit the while loop to aboard properly.

I want a pointer in a other structure to control the execution of the child. Simple reproducible example of this idea may boil to (beware, this code will spawn a zombie process):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct {
  void (*loop)();
  _Bool done;
} __state;

__state state;

void state_loop() {
  pid_t pid;
  switch(pid = fork()) {
  case -1:
    perror("Failed to fork!\n");
    exit(1);
  case 0:
    printf("Connecting..\n");
    printf("Child's adress: %p\n", &state.done);
    while(!state.done) {
      ;;
    }
    printf("Conected.\n");
  default:
    printf("Spawned a child..\n");
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
  }
}

__state state = {state_loop, 0};

typedef struct {
  void (*set_state)(_Bool *flag_p);
  void (*flip)();
  // Data
  _Bool *flag_p;
} __controller;

__controller controller;

void controller_set_state(_Bool *flag_p) {
  controller.flag_p = flag_p;
}

void controller_flip() {
  *controller.flag_p = (_Bool)1 - *controller.flag_p;
}

__controller controller = {
  controller_set_state, controller_flip
};

int main(void) {
  printf("%i\n", state.done);
  controller.set_state(&state.done);
  state.loop();
  controller.flip();
  printf("%i\n", state.done);
  printf("%p:%p\n", &state.done, controller.flag_p);
  return 0;
}
```

Example above does print the addresses of `server.done` and `controller.flag_p` from the parent process and `server.done` address from the child process.

How is that addresses are the same in all of the places, but the value in the child process reminds 0 after being changed by `controller.flip`?

Comment: Ya, thank you, this sounds better now.

Comment: If your `loop` function doesn't take any arguments, you should make that explicit via `void (*loop)(void)`.

Comment: You need to use some form of inter-process communication. You can use a file, a socket, shared memory, signals, or something like that, but you have to use something. Simplest might be to create a pipe before you call `fork` and simply close it in the parent to signal. Sending a `SIGUSR1` would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork` creates a separate process which gets its own virtual address space.  With a few exceptions (see the documentation for `fork`), the child process is an exact duplicate of its parent.  That means it gets its own separate copy of `state` at the same virtual address.

If you don't specifically need a separate process, you could spin off a thread instead.  Threads share the same memory space and so would have access to the same `state`.  However, you would need to protect the read/write of `state`'s fields via something like a `pthread_mutex_t`.